# sftp の mput コマンドでフォルダ構造を保ったままアップロードしたい

Tags: windows

Windows 10でバッチファイルを使用し、`sftp` でLinuxにファイルアップロードするようにしたいのですが

```
mput -r ./upload/* /mnt/mydoc
```

としたときに、送信元の `upload/` フォルダの下に

```
upload/
 　img/
　　　gif/
　　　jpg/
```

となっていた場合、gifフォルダとjpgフォルダがimgの下に作成されずに
/mnt/myDocの下に直接gif,jpgフォルダが作成されてしまいます

uploadフォルダの中には他にも色々ファイルがあり、変更もちょくちょくあるので出来ればワイルドカードを使いたいのですが
アップロードしたいフォルダ構造を崩さずにフォルダとファイルをアップロードするにはどう記述したらいいのでしょう

Comment: `ffftp` 等の「ミラーリングアップロード」でどうでしょう？　最近の `ffftp` は `sftp` にも対応したと聞いています（使わなくなって久しいので最近の事情には疎いですが）

Comment: 一応デフォルト状態のウインドウズPCで動作しなければならないバッチなのでffftpだとちょっと無理です

Comment: [sftp](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp) には`mput` が無いようなのですが…？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mput` で転送元のフォルダ構造を保ったままのアップロードは難しいようなので、代わりの案を挙げてみます。

#### 方法1

転送元のフォルダ構造が固定であるなら、各ディレクトリに移動しながら `mput` を複数回実行する方法が考えられます。

#### 方法2

1つの ZIP ファイルにまとめてしまい、転送後に展開する方法です。

- 転送元であらかじめ基準となるフォルダを ZIP ファイルにまとめてしまう。
- `put` で Linux に転送。
- Linux 側で crontab などを仕込み、ZIP ファイルを展開する。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
無いのだったら、おっしゃるとおりZIPにまとめるか結局個別でファイルを指定するしかないみたいですね・・・